# Is it possible to paste in all tmux panes simultaneously using tmux copy & paste?

Tags: tmux

If I run `tmux` with synchronized panes, I can type and have the text appear in all panes at the same time.

Furthermore, if I use the mouse to select text and copy it into the system clipboard, I can paste and have it appear in all panes.

However, if I want to use `tmux` native copy (`prefix-[`) and paste (`prefix-]`), the pasted content appears in **only one pane**.

**Is there a native tmux way to paste in all panes of the current window?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **native tmux way** so far to achieve it. Because pasting buffer is calling `paste-buffer` command. It can only be applied on a single pane, with the optional `-t`.

Your system clipboard approach worked because you were using the send-key (I guess) in key mapping.

What you can try is, if you have synchronized panes, you type in one pane: `tmux pasteb`, you will see that this command was typed in all panes, however the result/output comes only to your current pane.